# How to detect click outside of class component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My task is to detect the click outside of component. I've been trying to implement the below code with typescript, but cant find what type should i give to `handleClickOutside` event so that `event.target` doesn't throw an error: `Argument of type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node | null'`. No hooks are allowed. Please help.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class OutsideAlerter extends Component {
  private wrapperRef: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.wrapperRef = React.createRef();
    this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  handleClickOutside(event) { //problem is here
    if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.current.contains(event.target)) { //and here
      alert("You clicked outside of me!");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.wrapperRef}>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I found an answer. You have to give the `event` type `Event` and use event.target as  `event.target as Node`

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign a type to your event, note that since you are registering the handler on the document, you need to specify that.

```
handleClickOutside(event: React.MouseEvent<Document>) {
```

See https://www.carlrippon.com/React-event-handlers-with-typescript/

Comment: Ha, I believe that is because you are registering on `document`, which is not an `HTMLElement`. Try `React.MouseEvent<Document>`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I just used `Event` as type of `event` and `event.target` as `Node`.